# Help with bulk/batch insert into Sybase from XML with .NET

Tags: c#, database, .net-3.5, sybase, bulkinsert

I want to insert thousands of records into a [Sybase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sybase) database. Is there any good tool available to help me manage bulk inserts with .NET?

The records come in as an XML message to my web service. In the web service I need to load these records into a Sybase database and send load status back.

Comment: from where do the thousands of records come? A file? a webservice? You can't use a bulk import tool from sybase? Can you explain why .net is needed in this bulk import? What requirement/feature is key to this descision?

Comment: Record comes as XML message to my webservice, In webservice I need to load this record into sybase database and send load status back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like that, and it helped reduce load time significantly,

```
    public static void InsertModelValueInBulk(DataSet employeData, int clsaId, int batchSize)
    {
        string[] insertStatement = new string[batchSize];
        using (var connection = GetOdbcConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();
            var tran = connection.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                int j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < employeData.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var row = employeData.Tables[0].Rows[i];
                    var insertItem = string.Format(@"select '{0}',{1}", row["name"], Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]);
                    insertStatement[j] = insertItem;
                    if (j % (batchSize-1) == 0 && j > 0)
                    {
                        var finalQuery = @" INSERT INTO employee (id, name)
                                         " + String.Join(" union ", insertStatement);
                        using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(finalQuery, connection, tran))
                        {
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        j = 0;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        j = j + 1;
                    }
                }

                if (j > 0)
                {
                    var finalQuery = @"INSERT INTO employee (id, name)
                                     " + String.Join(" union ", insertStatement,0,j-1);
                    using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(finalQuery, connection, tran))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                tran.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                tran.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you may need to use BCP

bcp database_name.owner.table_name in datafile -n -U username -P password

[Sybase BCP link](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/util/@Generic__BookTextView/2105;pt=2262)

However, you may need to write the records to a file first then use the `Process` class to execute BCP on the file you have just written.

AFAIK there is no Sybase equivalent of `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: Can I invoke BCP from webservice? Will I need BCP installed on web server?

Comment: @Brijesh: Yes and yes. Though if you have Sybase installed then BCP will already be available. Or should be anyway. It's a utility that's usually installed with other Sybase options.

Comment: @Brijesh: You will need to ensure that the account under which your webservice is running has suitable O/S permissions to a.) Execute a process b.) has IO permissions applicable to writing your data to disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to insert only thousands of records then don't bother about bulk load. Plain old batch insert performs this insert in a few seconds.

A .NET web service with [BCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_Copy_Program) is a too complex solution.
Try BCP if you have to insert more than a million records.

Comment: Can you share an example of plain old batch insert? Thanks

Comment: See oficial tutorial 
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/performing-batch-updates-cs